# Как нарисовать знак "Х" с помощью SVG и CSS?

Tags: css, анимация, svg, css-animation

Мне нужно создать анимацию знака **"Х"**  для отказа от действий.

Я нашел отличный пример анимированного знака **"V"**  для подтверждения успешных действий.
Этот символ сделан с помощью кода  Кривой Безье . Я пробовал читать код и пытаюсь сделать знак "Х", но без успеха.
Можете ли вы, пожалуйста помочь мне ?
Ссылка для реализации знака "V"   на  [кодепен](http://codepen.io/haniotis/pen/KwvYLO).

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}
.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}
@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to draw X Sign with SVG+CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36011117/7394871) от участника  [@EVH671](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445136/evh671).</sub>

Comment: Вам нужен, что бы таким же образом появлялся крестик?

Comment: Вряд ли у меня что-то путное выйдет :)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011117/how-to-draw-x-sign-with-svgcss/36011513#36011513

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам просто нужно изменить определение пути (path), для формирования знака `"X"` и заменить `pattern` черточки и её смещение, чтобы компенсировать изменение длины пути.

С дополнительным элементом `<Path>`, и применяя некоторые дополнительные `CSS` свойства, вы можете  нарисовать `"X"` за два преобразования.

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}
.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 29;
  stroke-dashoffset: 29;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}
@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M16 16 36 36 M36 16 16 36" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to draw X Sign with SVG+CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011513/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>